# Dragging an object outside of a overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If you'll take a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/hunterscott/JYLVQ/
You'll notice that if you try to drag the image, you can see the helper move, but it won't leave the gallery box. I have a feeling this is a CSS thing, but I'm not sure where it is.

Edit: Sorry, I need to be more specific, since that fiddle is pretty watered down from the full project. Gallery-wrap has to be set to overflow:hidden because it is an image carousel that shows 5 images at a time, and the rest are hidden. The user clicks arrows to advance through them. If I make gallery-wrap visible, then the images that shouldn't be seen are seen stacked below the first 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#gallery-wrap
```

is the culprit, it has overflow:hidden; set.

EDIT: ah, thanks for the clarification. [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258352/jquery-ui-getting-one-element-out-of-a-displayhidden-element-when-dragging)

Comment: I think he needs the `overflow:hidden` set, but still be able to drag the thing out of the div.

Comment: Ah, in that case, is [this answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258352/jquery-ui-getting-one-element-out-of-a-displayhidden-element-when-dragging) of any help?